# Move files with new filenames

Tags: bash, perl

I have files

```
/folder/file1.mp4
/folder/file2.wmv
/folder/file3.mov
```

I need to move them to new folder with new filename, which randomly generated from 12 symbols.

```
/new-folder/345457567452.mp4
/new-folder/890897687685.wmv
/new-folder/235344783456.mov
```

How can I do it?

The problem is: I don't know extesion of original file, and I need rename only name of ile and save extension.

Comment: Try: `rename` utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion to extract the file extension (`${file##*.}` deletes everything up to the last dot).

The `$RANDOM` variable can be used to create the random names.

```
for file in folder/file* ; do
    newname=''
    for i in {1..12} ; do
        newname+=$(( RANDOM % 9 ))
    done

    newname=new_folder/$newname."${file##*.}"
    if [[ -f $newname ]] ; then
        echo "Target $newname already exists. $file not moved." >&2
    else
        mv "$file" "$newname"
    fi
done
```